# C++ hash string X number of times and then write to console

Tags: c++, for-loop, hash, pseudocode

Before i start i would like to say that i am a complete beginner when it comes to c++, but i am familiar with other programming languages.

I am attempting to write a code that will take a string, and hash it X number of times.

Pseudo code:

```
Times to hash = X
String to hash = "Hello world"
For i=1 to 10
   hash string
next
Console write string that has been hashed X times.
```

I have done some research and i have modified [this code](https://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/md5-c-implementation/), but the problem is the hash algorithm is md5 and i would like it to be sha256 (but i couldn't find an useful code i could adapt)

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  MD5 md5 ;
  string str1(md5.digestString( "String" ));
  cout << str1;
  return 0;
}
```

I have had look a several for loops but i can seem to get any of them to work but here is on of my attempts:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i<50; ++i) {
    cout << "Hello world";
}
```

The error for the for loop:

```
2   1   C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp    [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'for'
2   8   C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp    [Error] 'i' does not name a type
2   14  C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp    [Error] expected unqualified-id before '++' token
```

But im getting errors like "i is not a type", im assuming variable type, but im not quite sure what to do next.

I am somewhat reluctant to learn C++ fully at this time as this is just a tiny section of the project that i am working on.

**Edit**

Form the comments and answers i have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "md5.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count = 50;
    std::string prev = "stringtohash";
    std::string cur;
    
    for(int i=0; i < count; ++i) {
        cur = md5.digestString(prev);
        prev = cur;
    }
    
    std::cout << cur;
    return 0;
}
```

But it returns the error: `[Error] 'md5' was not declared in this scope`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cout "Hello world"` this is not valid.

Comment: @Borgleader I missed out the `<<`, edited.

Comment: Missed `;` at the end of `cout << "Hello"` ....

Comment: @PiotrNycz, Edited, like i said im new to C++

Comment: Could you please copy paste the actual code, and error message?

Comment: Try to search in internet the following "sha256 freeware C". Then try to use one of what you found for single string, Then try to do it X times in loop. Then if you have problems - ask for help...

Comment: The error message  doesn't fit the code at all (the code seems ok). Can you create an mcve?

Comment: Please remove the C tag - This is C++. Then, check your pseudo-code: you have `Times to hash = X` and then `For i=1 to 10` but I think you want `For i=1 to X`. Finally, please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where we can reproduce your error.

Comment: @FabioTurati When i run the for loop in my question i revive the error: "[Error] 'i' does not name a type", can you reproduce the error?

Comment: Your response to @longwei, ` 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type` makers no sense when including string. Remove the include of md5.h and references to it so you just have a glorified "hello world" with a loop. This should allow you to see if there is a mistake like a missing `;` in md5.h. Won't find it, but you've narrowed down the search area.

Comment: new error is because you've removed the definition of md5 you had in the previous version. `MD5 md5;`. If putting that definition back in breaks other stuff, seriously examine `MD5`.

Comment: Moving iostream's include above md5's helping says md5 is missing at least one required include. Best to keep headers self-consistent by having the header include everything it needs.

Comment: Oh, and consider removing that `using namespace std;` For why, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @user4581301 After adding MD5 md5; back into the code i revive the following error `[Error] no matching function for call to 'MD5::digestString(std::string&)'`.

Comment: Recommend adding md5.h to your question unless it's a huge file.

Comment: @user4581301 A link to it is in the question, i didn't add the code to the question as it is over 100 lines long.

Comment: `std::string prev` is not the same as `char *string`. Normal trick is to call `prev.c_str()`, but that returns `const char *` (I am constant., Do not try to change me!), so you can't use that either. As loath as I am to say this, you're going to have to stop using std::string or do stupid copies from std::string to char arrays or modify the MD5 class.

Answer (score 0):

The loop may be this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
     cout << "Hello world"
}
```

For sha256 check http://www.cryptlib.com/

Added the "<<" operator as Fabio Turati said.

Comment: The for loop returns an error "i does not name a type."

Comment: That `cout` is wrong. It's missing both the `<<` operator and the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Ups, my mistake with the << operator

Comment: `cout "Hello world"` - invalid syntax. You should replace it with `cout << "Hello world";`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right compiler?, if I execute this code:     #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main() {
 for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
     cout << "Hello world";
 }
    return 0;
} it works (https://www.codechef.com/ide) [I didn't know how to post like "code" here :/ ]

Comment: @Johna I am still getting an error even with codechef: http://i.imgur.com/lXOYlWx.png

Comment: You miss the rest of the code, try adding [ #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main() {] before de for loop and, and [return 0; } ] after

Comment: Thats what i was missing, now the loop seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

almost same as your pseudo code :)

```
int count = 50;
std::string cur = "stringtohash";

for(int i=0; i < count; ++i) {
    cur = whateverlib.md5.digest(cur );
}

std::cout << cur;
```

Comment: The code looks good but i am reciveing the following errors: `2 6 C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp [Error] 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
3 6 C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp [Error] 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
5 1 C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'for'
5 14 C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp [Error] 'i' does not name a type
5 25 C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\Hash.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before '++' token`

Comment: Std string doesn't copy on write anymore, as it's previous implementation is illegal in c++11.  Aside from that I dont understand the purpose of prev

Comment: After help form @Johna I have mannaged to get the code to work with just 1 error `[Error] 'whateverlib' was not declared in this scope`.